# React Native App Crash when in Production

Tags: ios, react-native, crash

I recently pushed an update to our React Native app. Everything was running fine, however during the review, Apple rejected the update because the app crashed on boot. 
Here are the meaningful lines the report:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1d3b30ec4 __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1d2d01a40 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   vesali_app                      0x101c9f478 RCTFatal + 447
3   vesali_app                      0x101c9cf20 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] + 491
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1d3b38630 __invoking___ + 143
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1d3a16450 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 291
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1d3a17034 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 59
7   vesali_app                      0x101cb28f4 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 491
8   vesali_app                      0x101cf6770 facebook::react::invokeInner+ 25552752 (RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 247
9   vesali_app                      0x101cf64d0 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke+ 25552080 (unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 87
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d35696c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 23
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d356a484 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d3511bd0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 591
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d3512718 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 431
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1d351aeb8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 599
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1d374d0dc _pthread_wqthread + 311
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1d374fcec start_wqthread + 3
```

Any tips/suggestions are greatly appreciated,thanks a lot !

Comment: I am facing the same issue. App works fine in the devices we have. Apple reports a crash and it is rejected. Did you find the cause of the issue ?